# AngularJS ui-route: invoke with objects instead of parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I would have a question concerning ui-router: when I invoke my router only with parameters all works fine.
My question now would be if it is possible to transfer also javascript- objects from my html to my router?

the invokaction of the router looks like this:

```
ui-sref="auth.name({parameter1: '{{parameter1}}', parameter2: '{{parameter2}}'})"
```

and this is my router:

```
function getScheduleConfirmationState() {
var state = {
    name: 'auth.name',
    url: '/url/:parameter1/:parameter2',
    templateUrl: 'url/to/html/my.html',
    controller: 'MyController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {
        myService: 'myService',
        dataForController: function myFunction(myService, $stateParams) {
        return myService.getDataFromBackend();
        }
    }
}
return state;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, but you cannot supply them as parameter in the URL:

First of all you can put the object as it is into ui-sref:

```
ui-sref="auth.name({parameter1: parameter1, parameter2: parameter2})"
```

Your state would have to add one property `params`:

```
    params: {
        parameter1: null,
        parameter2: null
    }
```

Remove the parameters from the URL, since objects can only be transferred hidden:

```
url: '/url'
```

In the controller of the target state `auth.name` you would need to inject the `$stateParams` service. Then you can access these parameters by:

```
$stateParams.parameter1 
$stateParams.parameter2
```

I hope the concept is clear enough for you. If not just let me know.